# Ruby on Rails search form doesn't recognise capital letters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, full-text-search

I have a working search form in my RoR app however it doesn't recognise capital letters. So if i search for something it has to be case sensitive. I tried adding UPPER in the search method however it raises an error. How do I get it not be case sensitive?

Here is the controller:

```
def index
if params[:search]
  @restaurants = Restaurant.search(params[:search]).order("created_at DESC")
else
  @restaurants = Restaurant.joins("LEFT JOIN reviews ON restaurants.id = reviews.restaurant_id").group("restaurants.id").order("AVG(reviews.rating) DESC NULLS LAST")
 end
end
```

This is the method from the model:

```
def self.search(query)
 where("name LIKE ?", "%#{query}%")
end
```

And finally the form:

```
<section class="search-form">
      <%= form_tag(restaurants_path, :method => "get", id: "search-form", class: "navbar-form navbar-left") do %>
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "Search restaurants", :autocomplete => :off, class: "form-control", id: "search-field", required: "required" %>
        </div>
          <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil, id: "search-button", class: "btn btn-default" %>
      <% end %>
 </section>
```

Would appreciate any advice. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can always convert `params[:search]` to lowercase, I'd do something like this:

```
Restaurant.search(params_search).order("created_at DESC")

private 

def params_search
 params[:search].to_s.downcase
end
```